# How to open multiple modal on reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog

I have multiple modal and need an better way to handle them. At the moment they look like this

```
 const [modalShow, setModalShow] = useState(false);
  const [modalShow2, setModalShow2] = useState(false);
  const [modalShow3, setModalShow3] = useState(false);

  const handleModal = () => {
    setModalShow(!modalShow);
  };
  const handleModal2 = () => {
    setModalShow2(!modalShow2);
  };
  const handleModal3 = () => {
    setModalShow3(!modalShow3);
  };


         <li>
            23.02.1 (09/01/2023)
            <button
              className="btn-modal"
              onClick={handleModal3}
            >
              <span>open</span>
            </button>
            <Dialog
              open={modalShow3}
              onClose={handleModal3}
              aria-labelledby="responsive-dialog-title"
              id="dialog"
            >
              <ModalContainer id="container-modal">               
                <div className="div-btn">
                  <iframe 
                    title="modal3"
                    className="frame"
                    src={vers3}
                    allowfullscreen= {true}
                  ></iframe>
                </div>
              </ModalContainer>
            </Dialog>
          </li>
```

Each

has a different modal

I've tried using some material UI components but it did not work

Comment: Do you want the modals to be in front of each other?

Comment: no, opening separately

Comment: So displaying them in line?

Comment: wait a minute pls, I am making a code sandbox for this problem :blink

Comment: Is this what you were looking for? https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-farrell-fq3h6x?file=/src/App.js:126-261

Comment: not really, I have a list of modals, like 1, 2, 3. When I click the first it opens, then the second. Not one inside the other